# Include file into PHP class

Tags: php, oop, include

I'm trying to create a Config class so I can easily edit my site info. All my config is saved in a php (not .inc) file but I can't seem to access it from my `Config.php` class. What am I missing?

```
// My folders
sunrise.app
    - conf.php
    - Classes\Sunrise\Config.php
public
    - sample.php
```

My config file:

```
// conf.php
return array(
    'sample' => 'Foo'
);
```

Here's my class:

```
// Classes\Sunrise\Config.php
namespace Classes\Sunrise;
class Config {

    private static $config;

    public static function setup() {
        ob_start();
        include '../sunrise.app/conf.php';
        self::$config = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    public static function all() {
        return self::$config;
    }

}
```

My use of autoload works fine so that's not an issue. The only thing I can't get is when I run `Config::all()` all I get is `NULL`, an empty string, or an error message. What am I missing?

```
// Sample php file
use Classes\Sunrise\Config;

Config::setup();
echo print_r(Config::all());
```

**More:**

I play around with the path in `include` but still nothing:

- `conf.php`
- `../conf.php`
- `../../conf.php`
- `../sunrise.app/conf.php`

I sometimes get this error

```
<br /> <b>Warning</b>: include(../../conf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\sunrise\sunrise.app\Classes\Sunrise\Config.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: include(): Failed opening '../../conf.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\sunrise\sunrise.app\Classes\Sunrise\Config.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

Comment: You could try to use `__DIR__`

Comment: Nope. I get `<br /> <b>Warning</b>: include(__DIR__/../../conf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\sunrise\sunrise.app\Classes\Sunrise\Config.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: include(): Failed opening '__DIR__/../../conf.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\sunrise\sunrise.app\Classes\Sunrise\Config.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dirname(__FILE__).'../../conf.php'` should work.

Note as you used `return` in the config file make sure you assign the return value of `include` into a variable.

```
$conf = include dirname(__FILE__).'../../conf.php'
```

You dont need `ob_*` functions at all. Because the config file does not output anything. It just executes code.  So following `setup` method is enough for this.

```
 public static function setup() {
    self::$config = include dirname(__FILE__).'../../conf.php'
 }
```

Comment: It worked! I'm guessing the problem was with the use of `ob_*` functions?

Comment: They have no effect here. In fact they are useless. As you used `return` in config file all you had to do is assign it to some variable.